# UIManagedDocument migrate data model

Tags: core-data, migration, icloud, uimanageddocument

I am working on an iPhone app that uses a subclass of `UIManagedDocument` and stores its documents on iCloud.

It was all working fine until I changed my core data model / scheme (adding a new model version - like I had several times in the past few weeks). 
I added a new property and changed the data type of one of the existing properties.

Now when I run my app I don't seem to be able to load my documents with `UIManagedDocument`'s `-openWithCompletionHandler:`. 
I can create new documents and read/write those.
If I change the data model version back 1 then I am able to read the existing docs, but not the new ones.

From what I understand I am only do lightweight migrations to the data model and `UIManagedDocument` is supposed to handle that right?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a subclass of UIManagedDocument you may want to try overriding managedObjectModel like so:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"<ModelNameHere>" ofType:@"momd"];
    NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];

    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Given below is based on my understanding:

**NOTE - I haven't tried it for iCloud but I have tested it for non-icloud and seems ok.**

`UIManagedDocument` configures the `managedObjectModel` and a Persistent Store Coordinator by itself

When migration needs to be done, just set the `UIManagedDocument`'s `persistentStoreOptions`

```
//Note - In this example, managedDocument is a UIManagedDocument property

self.managedDocument.persistentStoreOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
```

**Refer:**

- [Apple Documentation on Core Data Versioning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)
- [Point of using NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729255/point-of-using-nspersistentstorecoordinator)

Comment: where should these line of codes be put? I'm going through a similar problem. I placed it after my `self.database = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];` But my migration doesn't seem to be successful.

Comment: Pls check the Apple Documentation link provided in my answer, the documentation explains all the steps required . I have used the above code in AppDelegate's `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`.

Comment: @user1046037 Awesome! This worked for me and saved me a ton of time.

Comment: This one is definitely the correct answer. The one above is hard to understand and could cause the app to use different models.